# Vue: Restricted to using lower cased component names?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've built Vue apps before and I normal name my components as followed:  `LoginComponent`. 
I noticed if I do this when using Vuetify, it throws an error for an unregistered component if I register my component as `StatsComponent` and try to use it as `<StatsComponent></StatsComponent>` and use it as such, but it is fine when I register it as `statscomponent` and use it like that, `<statscomponent></statscomponent>`, like the code below.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import StatsComponent from './components/admin/StatsComponent';

Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.component('statscomponent', StatsComponent);  <---- this works
Vue.component('StatsComponent', StatsComponent);  <---- using casing like this doesn't when Vuetify is installed


const opts = {
  theme: {
    dark: false,
    themes: {
      light: {          
      },
      dark: {      
      }
    }
  }
}




new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(opts),
    el: "#app-admin",
    components: {
        StatsComponent
    },

    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("XXX")
    }
});
```

Comment: Have a read over of [component naming practices](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Base-component-names-strongly-recommended)

Comment: thanks for this -- never saw this before.